# Using URL variables on a custom WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, query, urls, page-template

## Background

I have a page with a custom template 'listen', with a custom wp_query running on it...

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-audio' ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

## The Problem

When I try and filter the posts on this page with url variables (*example.com/listen/?category_name=thebigshow*), nothing changes, even if I spell the category name incorrectly.

How can I use this method to filter the 'listen' page, by 'category_name' (show name)?

Thanks, Andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress doesn't handle this logic qutomatically so you will have do do it manually.

What you need to do is:

1. Read the url parameter with get_query_var( 'category_name' );
2. injects it in your custom WP_Query:

   ```
    $custom_query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                 'field'    => 'slug',
                 'terms'    => array( 'post-format-audio' ),
             ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                 'field'    => 'slug',
                 'terms'    => get_query_var( 'category_name' ),
             )
         )
    );
   ```

Note that if you decide to pass an arbitrary variable instead of category_name, you will need to declare it before using it.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

Comment: Adding it to query vars isn't required, you can access the value via `$_GET`.

Comment: A related question regarding url rewrites for the query structure above - [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206819/rewrite-rule-for-custom-page-with-query-vars-in-url]