# Rewriting a page with a custom parameter

Tags: url-rewriting

I have an issue similar to this one: [Rewrite Rule for Custom Page with Query Vars in URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206819/rewrite-rule-for-custom-page-with-query-vars-in-url)

We have those two rules we're trying to add through the [Rewrite plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/).
[image: rewriting rules]

We tested it and the GET parameters don't seem to follow as shown here.
[image: rewriting analysis]

When using PHP on that resulting page to show the $_GET values, it's empty.
The red bar on top of the parameters shows a tooltip saying "This query variable is not public and will not be saved".

Our page is available here: https://v2.magikweb.ca/commande

But we'd like to feed it dynamic with one or two parameters as such:
https://v2.magikweb.ca/commande/web-hosting/plan-name

How do you make a custom GET parameter not public so this would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, we had to add the "query variables" into the `functions.php` of our theme to add them to the public variables.

```
function add_query_vars_filter($vars){
  $vars[] = "subject";
  $vars[] = "param";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter');
```

This allowed us to retrieve the variables' value this way.

`$subject = get_query_var('subject', false);`